# What do you call a torus with a center?

Tags: geometry, terminology, solid-geometry

This may be a dumb question, but what is a torus with a center called? (Imagine a doughnut, without it's center taken out.)

Comment: A doughnut is a torus, and with the hole filled it is a sphere, see [here](https://www.google.at/search?q=torus+and+sphere&client=safari&rls=en&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=lEhvVdqVBMauUZmZgrgO&ved=0CCkQsAQ&biw=1484&bih=1332).

Comment: A sphere, or ellipsoid, or 'simply connected'

Comment: @DietrichBurde

Of course! That makes a lot of sense. Thank you.